# SSIS - Use data from Flat File Source in Subject Line of Send Mail task

Tags: email, variables, ssis

We import files from an FTP. The file could be named anything.csv.

Every 15 mins, we use a Script Task to pull the directory listing of an FTP folder; then in a ForEach Loop Container (using Variable Enumerator) we download each FTP file, process it, delete it from the FTP and send a generic "Complete" email to confirm a file has been processed.

Is there a way we can use one of the columns ([ClientName]) in the anything.csv data file and put in the Subject line of the email we send out. So it reads "[ClientName] order has been imported"

I've tried using an Object variable (via a Recordset Destination and it's VariableName), but I get the error "the datatype of variable "User::Subject" is not supported in an expression".

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one client name per .csv file, you need to populate a string-type variable with just one clientname from the file.   Then you will be able to use that string variable to build the subject line expression.